# OAuthException 2500 (Unknown path components) when trying to register Achievement in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, achievements

I am trying to register a Facebook open graph achievement for an app. I obtain the app access token and post the following request using open graph API explorer:

https://graph.facebook.com/752901688356092/achievements&achievement=https://googledrive.com/host/0B1R_JKMKJc2KbkNqZTdleEZvOUE/brags/fb_achive_100_words.html&display_order=100&access_token=752901688356092|pPwn52AvX-Pkj2n8Tavopew5Rav

(note that app ID an access token above are not the real ones). However, I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /achievements&achievement=https://googledrive.com/host/0B1R_JKMKJc2KbkNqZTdleEZvOUE/brags/fb_achive_100_words.html&display_order=100&access_token=752901688356092|pPwn52AvX-Pkj2n8Tavopew5Rav",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500
  }
}
```

I have registered the app as a games type app and I have verified the achievement URL using open graph debugger (it shows the achievement and reports everything is fine). I also tried the above without the app-ID included in the access token. What could I be missing?

Comment: The Query String part of an URL is initiated by a question mark `?`, not an ampersand `&` – the latter is only to separate parameters within the query string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have an error in the way your URL is composed. The first GET parameter is supposed to be separated from the base URL by a `?`, not a `&`. Try the following :

https://graph.facebook.com/752901688356092/achievements?achievement=https://googledrive.com/host/0B1R_JKMKJc2KbkNqZTdleEZvOUE/brags/fb_achive_100_words.html&display_order=100&access_token=752901688356092%7CpPwn52AvX-Pkj2n8Tavopew5Rav

This throws another error, but that might also be caused by a missing AUTH token. Why don't you have a look at how [they suggest you do it](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/)? You probably need to check the setup of the achievement.

Comment: That did it, thanks! 
The facebook tutorial [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/open-graph/ ] is actually wrong - it specifies & instead of ?